# Resolve promise when map request are finished

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable

I am working on working on an bookmark page, we get the bookmark results with the bookmarked restaurant id. Then I map the response and push it as objects to an array.

I want to resolve the whole finished array so I can manipulate the data afterwards.

I have created an getData function which does a request to the bookmark api, in the onSucces I call a function called mapResult which looks like this:

```
mapResults(result: Array<any>, type: string): Promise<any> {
    const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        const requests = result.map((res, i) => {
            this.getRestaurantById(res.RestaurantId).then(restaurant => {
                const bookmarks = {
                     createdDate: res.CreatedDate,
                     restaurant: restaurant[0]
                };
                this.savedData[type].push(bookmarks);
            });
        });
        Promise.all(requests).then((completed) => {
            if(completed) {
                console.log(completed)
                resolve(this.savedData[type]);
            }
        })
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Where I subscribe to like this:

```
this.mapResults(result, type).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
});
```

But the `data` console.log is not the whole data array, it will just resolve the first object.

Why does the `Promis.all` function not wait for the map to finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems in your code:

- You don't `return` anything in the `result.map` callback
- `new Promise` is not necessary
- You should not use a state variable instead of the promise return value
- The `completed` variable does not make any sense

This code should work as expected:

```
mapResults(result: Array<any>, type: string): Promise<any> {
    // you don't need "new Promise" as "getRestaurantById" already returns a promise itself

    const requests = result.map((res) => {
        // here you forgot to return something
        return this.getRestaurantById(res.RestaurantId).then(restaurant => {
            return {
                createdDate: res.CreatedDate,
                restaurant: restaurant[0]
            };
        });
    });

    // using "completed" did not make any sense as it is just an array filled with "undefined"s
    return Promise.all(requests).then((restaurants) => {
        console.log(restaurants)
        // TODO store "restaurants" in "this.savedData[type]" if needed
        return restaurants;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer this solves it indeed! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't return your promise in the map.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but even if I do its the same result.